# React passing state to sibling component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

```
const ChatBox = ({ messages, sendInput }) => {
    <Card fluid className={theme} raised style={{ height: '100%' }}>
        <ChatLog
            messages={messages}
        />

         <RecordInput // has internal recording state
           sendInput={sendInput}
         />
    </Card>
}
```

My `ChatBox` contains a `ChatLog` and `RecordInput`.

The `ChatLog` contains the list of messages to be displayed.

The `RecordInput` is the user voice recording input to be sent to the `ChatLog`. This component has an internal `recording` state which can be `true` or `false`.

I want to send this `recording` state to the `ChatLog` which is a sibling component.

One solution: I can make the `ChatBox` a class component with `recording` state and pass that to both `ChatLog` and `RecordInput` .. but I would rather not refactor my functionless stateless component ..

Is there another way to do this? Perhaps redux or doing some sort of cloning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options:

1. Use redux to have a global state, as you already mentioned.
2. Add `RecordInput` class the `onRecordStatusChange` prop that will be called within that component every time the status is changed, and it will tell the parent component (`Card`) about the new status of the recording. This way you can save the status of the recording both in the parent and the child component, and the parent component can pass this data to other child components (siblings of the `RecordInput` component).
3. Use a `ref` on the `RecordInput` to check the status of the recording of inside that component (which I don't think is what you want in this specific situation, but you can do this).